# Maximizing probability or probability density

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen

We are given the relation $dP=r^2|R(r)|^2dr$. Also, we are given $R(r)$ for the 1s orbital, and we are required to find the *most probable radius* of the electron in the 1s orbital of a hydrogen atom.

It seems that the most probable radius $r$ should be that value that maximizes $P(r)$, the probability of finding the electron. From elementary mathematics, this should mean we solve the equations $dP(r)/dr=0$ and $d^2P/d^2r <0$. However, the correct answer is obtained by solving $d/dr (r^2|R(r)|^2)=0$, i.e maximizing the probability *density* and **not** the probability.

Why is this the case? Why are we not maximizing the *probability*? And if what we are doing *is* maximizing the probability, then why is it contradicting the elementary mathematical fact that $dP(r)/dr=0$ $d^2P/d^2r <0$ , for a maxima?

Comment: I think this is grounded in basic misunderstanding of what is *probability* and *probability density*.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of finding an electron at certain radius makes no sense. Instead, we calculate the probability of finding the electron in some volume region, defined by two spheres of radii $r$ and $r+dr$.
And we know that this probability is $$dP=r^2|R(r)|^2dr$$ So to maximize dP we have to maximize $r^2|R(r)|^2$.
The value of r we get by maximizing this function will be the most probable radius.
That's it.